# How to avoid using global?

Tags: node.js

I have very small nodejs app. Inside this application I define a model object in app.js like so:

```
global.model = {
    name: 'Foobar'
};
```

The model is not persisted to any storage but kept in memory all the time. My requirement is, to be able to read and modify this model inside any module of my app.

I read that it is bad practice to use `global`. What is the better way? Through exports? Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single module that creates and stores the model.  Then, any other module that wants to get the model can `require()` your model module and then call a method on it to fetch the single shared model.

in model.js:

```
var mymodel = {
   name: 'Foobar'
}

module.exports.getModel = function() { return mymodel;}
```

in any other module that wants to get the model:

```
var mymodel = require('./model').getModel();
```

---

If your model module would not generally be used for other things, then you could simplify it like this:

```
var mymodel = {
   name: 'Foobar'
}

module.exports = function() { return mymodel;}
```

in any other module that wants to get the model:

```
var mymodel = require('./model')();
```